# Sending email to a pair of users regardless of which one was addressed?

Tags: postfix, aliases

In the old sendmail I used to be able to backslash the usernames to prevent forwarding loops, however postfix 2 doesn't allow this syntax since complying with RFC822.

Here is my example sendmail aliases file:

```
fred: \fred, \jim
jim: \fred, \jim
fredandjim: jim
```

In postfix 2 the backslash is supposed to obsolete as it will detect that fred needs not to be forwarded to fred, however when it goes on to process jim it finds the loop back to fred and reports an error.

Can anyone suggest a way of implementing this in postfix?

Answer (score 1):

`recipient_bcc_maps` option will allow such setup.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps

Answer (score -2):

Well , If number of users are greater you can use Mailing list like Linuxusers@domain.com and add users to it. however for the other part you would have to enable forwarding for each of user:
For example :
Jim: Fred, john, kim
Kim: Fred, john ,jim
...... and so on.

Comment: jim aliasing to kim and kim aliasing to jim creates exactly the same forwarding loop